# Nodejs .ini files titles

Tags: javascript, node.js

.ini file:

```
[1]
1X = true
[2]
2X = true
[5] 
3X = true
```

How can i get titles [1], [2] and [5] from .ini files with ini module : https://www.npmjs.org/package/ini

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [example](https://github.com/isaacs/ini#usage) in the `ini` readme shows how to access them. If you want a list of them, just call `Object.keys()` on the return value:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    ini = require('ini');

var config = ini.parse(fs.readFileSync('./config.ini', 'utf8'));
console.dir(Object.keys(config));
```

If you want to be strict, you can check each property to make sure the corresponding value is an object (otherwise it is a key=value outside of a section). This would prevent the property `scope` (from the `ini` readme example) from being treated as a section. Example:

```
var sections = [],
    keys = Object.keys(config);
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; ++i) {
  if (typeof config[keys[i]] === 'object')
    sections.push(keys[i]);
}
console.dir(sections);
```

Comment: Show some native please. In microprocessor cant find require('ini') and also do not have enough choice to add third party modules. Can you share native ini parser?